# How to make a objective list with scoreboard Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I'm making a map in Minecraft Education Edition, I wanted to make like a scoreboard objective that stays in the side of the screen (I saw this in Hypixel first). But I can't make a list of objectives, like: If objective not completed: §4 Task. And if Completed §2 Task. I couldn't find anything in Youtube.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you're seeing is the entity's UUID, because entities only display the UUID on the scoreboard, not their custom names. Here's the correct way:

Remember how instead of a target selector, you can just type in a player name, like this?

```
tp ExpertCoder14 ~ ~ ~
```

You can also do that with the `/scoreboard` command, and you can even enter a player name even if that player is not actually online, and the scoreboard will still track it as if it is real:

```
/scoreboard players set §2ModBay 0
```

Answer (score 0):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Display_slots

[image]

The command you're looking for is:

```
/scoreboard objectives
```

To **create a new objective** in Bedrock, use this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add <objective: string> dummy [displayName: string]
```

To **show all the current objectives** on the screen with their display names and criteria, use this command *(warning: fails in Bedrock Edition if there are no objectives set!):*

```
/scoreboard objectives list
```

Finally, to display score info for a specific objective in a specific display slot:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay <list |sidebar> [objective: string]
```

Comment: When I tried to do it it showed some random numbers, I'll edit the post and add the image.

Comment: You have to add objectives before listing them, otherwise it shows nonsense values.